# GTX 580 Your system is running in low graphics mode

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system

After I installed Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit it ran smoothly for a couple of days, and then when I booted up another day it came with the message: "Your system is running in low graphics mode". I followed a guide and reinstalled the "desktop", then I installed the right graphics drivers: Nvidia experimental 310. Then it ran smoothly for 2 days, and now the error is back again. Is there a way to permanently fix the problem?

My build:

- GPU: Asus Nvidia GeForce GTX 580 1.5GB
- CPU: Intel i5.3470 (3.9ghz)
- mobo: Gigabyte Z77-D3H
- RAM: Kingston HyperX dual channel DDR3 4x4GB

The system is running on a Samsung 840 series SSD.

Comment: did you update your kernel after installing the driver? Please post the result of the following command
uname -r

Comment: Did you check [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and have tried almost everything suggested in this forum. After searching the log I found:

```
Failed to open DRM device
```

I searched and found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1066410).

The solution of Gavin ([#44](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1066410/comments/44)) worked for me. Reason seems to be that my system (SSD, i7) is booting too fast for the udev device driver.  Lightdm is trying to start before UDEV reports the graphics devices as being ready. As your system also boots from ssd this solution may help.

Inserting the line into `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` as shown in the bug report did the job for me.

Good luck,
Max

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Ubuntu two days ago and I also had this msg "Your system is running in low graphics mode" .. I surfed the internet trying to find a solution to this problem and this one worked : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riM5rWAoiKw

basically I just opened the terminal and wrote the code for ATI ( cause I am using an ATM graphic card ) ... I hope this help u , but I am totally new to U
buntu so don't understand what these code actually do :D

Comment: Remember this is a Q&A site - so keep on editing your question with new information - this section is for actual answers. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.